# How to prevent Url.RouteUrl(...) from inheriting route values from the current request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

Lets say you have an action method to display products in a shopping cart

```
 // ProductsController.cs
 public ActionMethod Index(string gender) {

      // get all products for the gender
 }
```

Elsewhere, in a masthead that is displayed on every page you are using `Url.RouteUrl` to create HREF links to other pages on the site :

```
 <a href="<%= Url.RouteUrl("testimonials-route", new { }) %>" All Testimonials </a>
```

This `testimonials-route` is defined in `global.ascx` by the first route below. 
Notice that the above call to `RouteUrl` does not provide a `gender`, but the route is defined with a default of 'neutral' so we'd expect Testimonials.Index("neutral") to be called.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
  "testimonials-route",
  "testimonials/{gender}",
  new { controller = "Testimonials", action = "Index", gender = "neutral" },
  new { gender = "(men|women|neutral)" }
 );

routes.MapRoute(
  "products-route",
  "products/{gender}",
  new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", gender = (string)null },
  new { gender = "(men|women|neutral)" }
 );
```

If someone visits the page `/products/women` we get an HREF to `/testimonials/women`
If someone visits the page `/products` then we get an empty HREF (the call to RouteUrl returns null).

But that doesn't make sense does it? `testimonials-route` is supposed to default to `'neutral'` for us if we don't provide a route value for it?

What turns out is happening is that `Url.RouteUrl(routeName, routeValues)` helper extension will first look in its `routeValues` parameter for a `gender` route value and if it doesn't find it in that dictionary it will look at the current URL that we're on (remember that Url is a UrlHelper object which has the context of the current request available to it).

This has a possibly nice effect of giving us a link to men's testimonials if we're on a mens product page, but that probably isnt what we want if we haven't passed a value in the `RouteUrl` call, and explicitly specified 'neutral' as a default in the `global.asax.cs` file.

In the case where we visited `/products/` we triggered the `'products-route'` route and the `Products(null)` method was called. The call to `Url.RouteUrl()` actually inherits THIS null value for `gender` when we're creating a URL using `testimonials-route`. Even though we have specified a default for `gender` in `'testimionials-route`' it still uses this null value which causes the route to fail and `RouteUrl` returns null. [note: the route fails because we have a constraint on (men|women|neutral) and null doesn't fit that]

It actually gets more scary - in that 'controller' and 'action' can be inherited in the same way. This can lead to URLs being generated to completely the wrong controller even when calling RouteUrl(...) with an explicit route name that has a default controller.

In this case once you've figured it out you can fix it quite easily in numerous ways, but it could in other cases cause some dangerous behavior. This may be by design, but its definitely scary.

Comment: adding a bounty a year and a half after the original question because (a) i'd like to know if the framework now does this for me and (b) i'm very curious why this only has 2 upvotes. thought it would be a common problem so wondering if i'm doing something wrong!

Comment: this was kicking my bootie, as the {domain} tag was lacking a value, but which the system is supposed to provide automatically. Once I changed this, it worked.

Comment: why don't you just call the RenderUrl like: `<a href="<%= Url.RouteUrl("testimonials-route", new { gender = "neutral" }) %>"` - so, nothing gets overwritten.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My solution was this :

An HtmlExtension helper method :

```
    public static string RouteUrl(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string routeName, object routeValues, bool inheritRouteParams)
    {
        if (inheritRouteParams)
        {
            // call standard method
            return urlHelper.RouteUrl(routeName, routeValues);
        }
        else
        {
            // replace urlhelper with a new one that has no inherited route data
            urlHelper = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext, new RouteData()));
            return urlHelper.RouteUrl(routeName, routeValues);
        }
    }
```

I can now do :

```
Url.RouteUrl('testimonials-route', new { }, false)
```

and know for sure it will always behave the same way no matter what the context.

The way it works is to take the existing `UrlHelper` and create a new one with blank 'RouteData'. This means there is nothing to inherit from (even a null value).

Comment: while I'm fine with my solution - I wish there was a way to enforce it globally, and not have to remember to always use this overload. hopefully MVC4 will give greater control over this.

Comment: I just ran into the exact same problem.  This was very helpful!  I was thinking of extending the HtmlHelper.RouteLink method to do the same thing for links, but am having trouble sorting out the syntax for instantiating a new HtmlHelper.

Comment: This is a good solution. For us these links were all in the same partial view so I just instantiated the new UrlHelper as a variable and used that variable in the partial instead of the standard Url property.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but why not set it up like this:

In your global asax, create two routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "testimonial-mf",
    "Testimonials/{gender}",
    new { controller = "Testimonials", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "testimonial-neutral",
    "Testimonials/Neutral",
    new { controller = "Testimonials", action = "Index", gender="Neutral" }
);
```

Then, use Url.Action instead of Url.RouteUrl:

```
<%= Url.Action("Testimonials", "Index") %>
<%= Url.Action("Testimonials", "Index", new { gender = "Male" }) %>
<%= Url.Action("Testimonials", "Index", new { gender = "Female" }) %>
```

Which, on my machine resolves to the following urls:

```
/Testimonials/Neutral 
/Testimonials/Male 
/Testimonials/Female
```

I'm not sure if this is an acceptable solution, but it's an alternative, no?

Comment: unfortunately (or fortunately perhaps!) the problem isn't in the parsing and routing of the URL. that works perfectly as expected - so your first route here is sufficient (if you add a default parameter). it is in the actual creation of the URL when existing route values get unexpectedly inherited. my solution I've been using for over a year - its just annoying when you need to use other overloads of RouteUrl or RouteLink and you need to create a tonne of method overloads. thanks for the answer though